# Looking for a tool to static code analyse

Tags: java, c++, code-analysis, continuous-integration

I'm looking for a tool which must meet certain requirements.
I do some research and at the moment JArchitect is closest to expectations.
This tool must:

- Work with Java (and maybe C++)
- Analyse code and create class inheritance graph, method and field use graph,
- Possibility to insert comments example on graph,
- Possibility to browse this graph (zoom, search, hyperlinks etc)
- (important) Possibility to visualize on graph code changes between two revisions (svn) with example heatmap. (if more changes in class, colour on red, if less changes, colour on green)
- It must run analyse from example command line, (or via plugin for bamboo, jenkins etc) after build on bamboo, and result (and browsing) must be available from the web.

Is it possible that such a thing exists at all?

Comment: My guess is that nothing exists that implements bullet 5, no.

Comment: JArchitect works with C++?